# Bidual of a space and Legendre-Fenchel transform

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, duality-theorems

Suppose I have a convex and lower semi-continuous functional $\psi:C_c(\mathcal{X})\to\mathbb{R}$ and that I know of a representation of the form:

\begin{equation}
\Lambda(\mu)= \sup_{f\in C_c(\mathcal{X})} \langle \mu, f\rangle - \psi(f).
\end{equation}
From Lemma 4.5.8, page 152 in [DZ10] I have that $\psi$ is the Legendre-Fenchel transform of $\Lambda$, meaning that it is lower semi-continuous with respect to the weak topology and that:
\begin{equation}
\psi(f) = \sup_{\mu\in C_c(\mathcal{X})^\star} \langle \mu,f\rangle - \Lambda(\mu).
\end{equation}

Moreover, from the Fenchel-Moreau theorem I know that $(\psi^\star)^\star = \psi$ and $(\Lambda^\star)^\star = \Lambda$.

From the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem I know that $C_c(\mathcal{X})^\star$ is the space or regular $\sigma$-finite signed measures $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{X})$.

So, if $\psi:C_c(\mathcal{X})\to\mathbb{R}$ then $\psi^\star:\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{X})\to\mathbb{R}$ but then I also know that $(\psi^\star)^\star:\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{X})^\star \to\mathbb{R} $ is equal to $\psi$.

What does this mean with respect to $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{X})^\star$? Does it mean that my $(\psi^\star)^\star$ is actually defined on a larger space (namely, $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{X})^\star$) and from the Fenchel-Moreau theorem all I can say that they both agree on $C_c(\mathcal{X})$ but I can't say anything on $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{X})^\star\setminus C_c(\mathcal{X})$? Or can one say something stronger (that preserves convexity) like : they agree on $C_c(\mathcal{X})$ but $\psi(f)=+\infty$ outside?

[DZ10] Amir Dembo, Ofer Zeitouni, Large Deviations Techniques and Applications, 2010, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-03311-7#toc

Comment: I don't think you can say anything stronger. Your guess that $\psi^{**}(f) = \infty$ outside of $C_c(\mathcal{X})$ is not true (indeed, if $\psi$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $\psi^{**}$ is continuous at $x_0$, and hence finite on some open neighbourhood).

Comment: Thanks! So you'd say that I can only state that they agree on $C_c(\mathcal{X})$ but can make no statements outside?

Comment: I'm looking at my copy of *Convex Functions: Constructions, Characterizations, and Counterexamples* by Borwein and Vanderwerff, and there are a few interesting tidbits about $\psi^{**}$, but nothing that explicitly allows for calculation based on $\psi$, unless in the canonical embedding of $C_c(\mathcal{X})$ in its second dual. Continuity is preserved, Frechet differentiability is preserved, and being bounded on bounded sets is preserved, but that's all I've got.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check out the reference as well!

Comment: For reference, check out section 4.4, page 171. Fact 4.4.4 (page 173) is what I sort of quoted. Check out the exercises too; sometimes the authors bury interesting nuggets in them.

Comment: If $\psi = 1/2\|\cdot\|^2$ on the original space, then $\psi^*$ looks likewise on the dual (using the dual norm) and on the bridal (using the bidual norm).